# Are guarded signals unsupported in block statement?

Tags: vhdl

I have 4 errors in the lines of this code:

```
architecture guard of FlipFlop is
begin
    bb: block(clk='1' and not clk'stable) is   -- errorHDLParsers:1074 Guarded signal unsupported in block statement.
    begin
        Q <= guarded D after tpl;     -- errorHDLParsers:1024 Guarded unsupported in signal assignment.
        Qb <= guarded not D after tph;  -- errorHDLParsers:1024 Guarded unsupported in signal assignment.
    end block bb;
end guard;

architecture guard2 of FlipFlop is
begin
    bb: block(clk='1' and not clk'stable) is  -- errorHDLParsers:1074 Guarded signal unsupported in block statement.
    begin
        Q <= D after tpl;
        Qb <= not D after tph;
    end block bb;
end guard2;
```

Why can't I define a block with guarded signals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your synthesis tool does not support this VHDL statement. I have checked the first architecture `guard` with integrated synthesizer of the Quartus-II 13.1 Web Edition for Windows and it works here. It is not unusual that the synthesis tools only provide a subset of the VHDL language.

I prefer to use a clocked process instead:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    Q <= D;
    Qb <= not D;
  end if;
end process;
```

The signals `Q` and `Qb` get there new values after the process has finished. Thus, the assignments use the value of `D` just before the rising clock edge.

Please note, that I have omitted the `after xy` delay. The actual timing is defined by the flip-flop built into the FPGA. Thus the specified delay is just ignored by synthesis tools. It is used only for RTL simulation.

**EDIT**: The second architecture `guard2` does not describe a flip-flop because the guard condition of the block does only control `guarded` signal assignments. Thus the code is equivalent to:

```
Q <= D;      -- after tpl
Qb <= not D; -- after tph
```

Comment: i use xilinx ISE 14.2 , synthesis tool XST.  what is your synthesis tool name in quartus?
because i used quartus 13 but i got this error :
"Error (12061): Can't synthesize current design -- Top partition does not contain any logic
"

Comment: @Prof.Hell I have used the integrated synthesizer of the Quartus-II 13.1 Web Edition for Windows. Did you specify the correct top-level in your Quartus project? Furthermore, you should upgrade your ISE to the lastest version 14.7 because the earlier ones (in the 14 series) have serious bugs, e.g., in the ISim simulator.

Comment: thanks I will test this in ISE 14.7 and I reply to you If i can't do that, thanks

Comment: I tried this with ise 14.7 but it give me same errors! but thanks.

Comment: @Prof.Hell - Architecture guard may not synthesize because IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (now rescinded)  6.1.3.6 Edge-sensitive storage using a guarded block, requires the target signal to be kind **register** as well as being expressible  as an equivalent process (as Martin shows). A guarded interface signal can only be kind **bus** (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.2 Interface object declarations). There appears to be confusion possible over the lack of declarations in the question. Using signal declarations without kind your architectures analyze but won't synthesize.